# multiple error-code configuration web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, error-handling

I'd like to direct all errors to my Errorsevlet without specifying all the codes explicitly.  Is there any way to do like that?

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>400</error-code>
   <location>/servlet/com.abc.servlet.ErrorServlet</location>
</error-page>
```

**And after reaching the ErrorServlet how can i get the stack trace of the error in the servlet. So that i can email the details when one error occurs. **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
    <location>/servlet/com.ibm.eisa.servlet.ErrorServlet</location> 
</error-page>
```

Try this one, all of your errors will be caught(500's) not 404 etc

Comment: Thanks.. if i want to catch all 400's then how is the configuration? Should i write separate error-page entries for all ?

Comment: Yes, you have to write separate entries.

Comment: Is there any way to get the stack trace from the servlet ? for sending a mail with the details...

Answer (score 12):

If you can upgrade, since Servlet 3.0 it's possible to have a generic error page for **all** errors, even those not caused by an exception (e.g. 404, 401, etc). Just omit the `<error-code>` or `<exception-type>` altogether so that you only have a `<location>`.

```xml
<error-page>
   <location>/errorServlet</location>
</error-page>
```

*Note that I replaced the URL to avoid the use of Tomcat's builtin and deprecated `InvokerServlet`*.

Comment: It seems that this "univeral" error-page is not supported even by lastest Tomcat 7.0.27... BalusC, what version your Tomcat are you running?

Comment: Confirmed, not supported yet by Tomcat (https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52135).

Comment: Working for Glassfish 4

Comment: Worked for me on tomcat 7.033

Comment: As per the [abovelinked issue report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52135) it was fixed in 7.0.29.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify all the desired codes explicitly, a wildcard mechanism is not supported. There are not that many codes, here is a full [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

To print out the stacktrace (e.g. in a comment, for debugging purposes), you could do something like this:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*"%>
<body>
<p>Sorry, there was an error.</p>
<!-- The full stacktrace follows:-->
<!-- 
<%
if (exception != null) {
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(out));
}
%> 
-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same concern and after some research I have found out that unfortunately there is no clear requirement to support default error page in Servlet 3.0 specs.

It's misleading that "error-code" or "exception-type" are optional tags in XSD so we tend to consider that default error page will be the one without "error-code" and without "exception-type" tag.

Some application servers (e.g. GlassFish) behave as we wish, take default error page, then following the order of specific error pages they override default error page.

I also tested this on WebLogic 12c and I couldn't get it working as on GlassFish. Below article gives more clues about Tomcat.

See: bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52135