# Exception and error handling configuration through web.xml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, web.xml

I am using Apache MyFaces and need to handle ViewExpiredException differently than other internal server errors.But I find that if I include error-code, 500; then in ViewExpiredException error also it takes the path of error-code.

Below is web.xml configuration:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</location>
</error-page> 

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

How to ensure that i can redirect to different URL for the above two case?
Referred [multiple error-code configuration web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237434/multiple-error-code-configuration-web-xml) and I am fine to replace the location with a single servlet; but how to capture the error in servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 issues here:

a. Identify javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException and redirect to /login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true. Without faces-redirect, redirecting to XHTML page will throw error

b. Ensure that other error with status code 500 is redirected to appropriate page.

These are resolved by:

1> Created a **servlet** which checks for HTTP code, and then checks if the error is due to ViewExpiredException or not. Based upon the error condition, the servlet forwards the request to specific URL.

> ```
> if (request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code") == 500) {
>       excep = (Class<? extends Exception>) request
>               .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception_type");
>       if (excep != null) {
>             if (excep.getCanonicalName().equalsIgnoreCase(
>                 "javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException")) {
>               //you can forward to another page like /login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true
>             } else {
>              //you can forward to different page with error message
>             }
>       }
>       }
> ```

2> Change in **web.xml** to forward all 500 exception to this servlet

> ```
> <error-page>
>     <error-code>500</error-code>
>     <location>/error</location><!-- here error is name of servlet -->
> </error-page>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For the ViewExpiredException why don't you try to handle the exception through CustomExceptionHandler and redirect the user to any Page you want through handle() method

Comment: You need to explain your answer a whole lot better, with a code sample

Comment: @hananAhmed:  Please share sample