# Tomcat error page issue

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, internal-server-error

I have configured my **tomcat6** `web.xml` to show my custom error page by adding these lines, [described here](https://ashrafhossain.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/how-to-display-custom-error-page-on-tomcat-6/)

```
 <error-page>

<error-code>500</error-code>

<location>/web_server_error.html</location>

</error-page>

<error-page>

<error-code>404</error-code>

<location>/web_server_error.html</location>

</error-page>
```

Also I came to know for each application deployed I need to put the same configuration as I did for ROOT, which is fine.

My issue is I have a simple folder `webapps/docs`. If I try to access any file existing in this folder say `/docs/mypage.html`, I can access it perfectly but if the file or directory doesn't exist in the folder like `docs/faq/` I need the same error page but tomcat is showing its 404 error page.

Actually I need it because my client mention this in a vulnerability list, i.e. in this scenario the attacker can get aware of the file structure so we need to show one page on all errors.

I need to know as it is a simple folder instead of any application how to handle this issue or is it simple impossible?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [multiple error-code configuration web.xml][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237434/multiple-error-code-configuration-web-xml

Comment: @ravi thnx for the reply, but  actually my problem is not that mentioned there, I have issue with the simple folder inside webapps ,hence no web.xml there...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Tomcat 6. Servlet 3.0 specifies global error pages but Tomcat 6 implements Servlet 2.5.

But it's possible to "workaround" by writing a [ErrorReportValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.html) class and register it. But beware: This is Tomcat specific!

Comment: thnx for the reply, may be I'm wrong , but plz point me I can write this class in my app and then I can handle the errors? but what if I don't have any application its simply a folder

Comment: then i would suggest you to switch to tomcat 7 ;)

Comment: actually I am testing this both in tomcat7 and tomcat6 :) having same issue,

Comment: in "webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml" ?

Comment: yes I have mentioned that I have made changes to ROOT of tomcat and placed my error page there  which is working if I enter any wrong app name and getting 404, but when if there exist any folder inside webapps, let say webapps/docs but inside it I requested any non existing file or directory than its shows tomcat's page which is exposing file structure

Answer (score 0):

The folder is not a web application.so your configure does not work!

Comment: thnx for the response, yes its pretty straight forward but how to handle this issue when I have a folder ,or simply is it impossible?